# How to search the word with max size in a given text in java?

Tags: java, string

If there is some text given, I need to search the word with maximum length.So I thought this way.

```java
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "java string split method by javatpoint";

        String words[] = str.split("\\s");//splits based on white space

        for(String w:words) {
            //System.out.println(w);

            String temp = w;
            if(temp.length()<w.length()) {
                String maxLengthString = w;
                System.out.println("maxLengthString is w");
                }else {
                    System.out.println("maxLengthString is temp");
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue are you facing? Please be a little more clearer

Comment: ``` temp ``` and w points to same word. So ``` if ``` will always fail

Comment: you should create  `String temp` outside of the for loop

Comment: I want to know the correct answer for a question like this?

Comment: I'd at least create a function that takes an array of words returns the largest of them, rather than performing output, if just to clear up your code.

Comment: In this case `largestWord(String[] words): String` would probably be a good *method signature*. Then you would separate your functionality from the splitting and the program output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the longest in temp, and only (try) to print it after the loop. Re-assign temp each time you encounter a longer word.

```
 for(String w:words) {
            //System.out.println(w);

            String temp = w;
            if(temp.length()<w.length()) {
                String maxLengthString = w;
                System.out.println("maxLengthString is w");
                }else {
                    System.out.println("maxLengthString is temp");
                }
            }
```

This will print each iteration, which is not what you want. In order to keep the longest word, you'll need to declare temp outside of the loop.

```
 String temp = "";
 for(String w:words) {
  // this will override temp only if the word is longer
  if ( w.length() > temp.length() ) {
    temp = w;
  }
 }
 // don't print harcoded "temp", but concatenate the value of the variable temp
 System.out.println("The longest word is: " + temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialise a string with **length 0** and compare it with the each string in the array and update the **maxString** found in each iteration in the end you will have the maxString.

```java
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "java string split method by javatpoint";

        String words[] = str.split("\\s");//splits based on white space
        String maxString = "";
        for(String w:words) {            
            if(w.length() > maxString.length()) {
                maxString = w;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(maxString);
}
```

Alternatively you can use `streams` for the same :

```java
    String str = "string split method by javatpoint javatpoint";

    String words[] = str.split("\\s");//splits based on white space
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList(words);

    Optional<String> result = 
    names.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
    System.out.println(result.get());
```

Comment: Why would you keep that maxLength?

Comment: @Stultuske yes not required i will update it .Thanks

Comment: Well, it saved a few method calls and made it stand out against the other, earlier posted answer. However, I'd go for simplicity as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Hey, kindly read the comments in the code, it will help understand what's going on.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         String str = "java string split method by javatpoint";

        String words[] = str.split("\\s");//splits based on white space

        int max =0;
        String maxWord = "";

        for(String w:words) {
            max = maxWord.length(); /* assigning the length of maxWord on every iteration since it might change */
            int mightBeNewMax = w.length(); /* always instantiating a newlenght that might be greater than previous, also this saves us the recreation below incase we wan to assign it as the new max length*/
            if(max<mightBeNewMax) {/* here we simply check the previous max against the new one */

/* getting to this block means we have a new max length so we simply update our initially declared variables above. */
                maxWord = w; 
                max = mightBeNewMax;
            }
        }

//Below is just a concatenated strings to make sense out of our code.
        System.out.println("maxLengthString is: "+ maxWord + " With length of: "+max);
    }
```

> Note: I removed your else statement because we don't want to do anything when the new string we're looping on is less than the previous one, so we only care about new longer lengths of strings.